# Unable to get stored procedure names in the dropdown using SQL authentication in azure logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am not able to retrieve stored procedure names in the dropdown if I use SQL Server authentication.

I can view/execute stored procedure from SSMS using the SQL Server account credentials. Login user has view/execute access for stored procedures.

I see the error shown here when I try to execute stored procedure step from a logic app :

> Could not retrieve values. BadGateway. Client request id:

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I was able to get SP names after deleting api connection and adding a new one. Is that the only solution? It seems a bad solution everytime I refresh permissions, I need to create a new connection and reconnect sql from all actions in the logic app. Any other alternative?

Comment: please mark the answer below or update your question if it does not provide guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some test, the latest permission will take some time to take effect(about 5-10 minutes). After a few minutes, you can go to the API connection and click "Refresh" button. Then go to logic app click "Change connection" and choose another API connection and then click "Change connection" again to choose back to the API connection. Then it will take effect. I test it with allow/not allow ip to connect to sql server.

Comment: I tried changing connection to AAD authentication and switch back to SQL authentication. That, didnt help. But, I didnt hit Refresh. Will try that next time.

Comment: A better solution I heard from Microsoft. -  if you’re looking at the designer in the portal, you can toggle to code view and then swap back to the designer, typically that will refresh the connection and pull new data in and allow you to set the value from the drop down. This is more an object of “when” the data is pulled for the form, which is on form initialization load.

Comment: Facing same issue but above given solutions do not fix it. In Procedure Name dropdown it shows "No Items" whereas there are Store Procedures in the Azure SQL MI database. Any better solution for this issue?